# I need to make a time based scoreboard work better

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I've been working on the google dinosaur game using turtle and I can't get the scoreboard to constantly update so that after every second it adds 100 points. Any help is VERY appreciated because this is for my finals.
Thanks
--Shay

edit:
its not letting me put in the code because its too long

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [mcve]. I don't think you need the entire game, just a toy example that reproduces only the code relevant to the scoreboard showing where you got stuck. Otherwise, the question is too broad to be answered and the thread devolves into a bunch of people posting random code that's probably only partially relevant to your problem or helpful to future readers. See also [how do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Thanks.

Comment: "its not letting me put in the code because its too long"—we don't need (or want) all of your code. Just a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something:

```
import turtle

delay = 0.1 # For the mainloop
count = 0 # To track when a second past
score = 0 # The score count

pen = turtle.Turtle(visible=False) # The turtle which will write the score
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0,200)
pen.write('Score: {}'.format(score),align='center',font=('Arial',10,'bold'))

while True: # Main game loop
    time.sleep(delay) # 1 frame per 0.1 second

    count += 1

    if count == 10: # When count is 10, that means 10*0.1 seconds have past
        score += 100
        pen.clear()
        pen.write('Score: {}'.format(score),align='center',font=('Arial',10,'bold'))
        count = 0 # Set count to zero to start tracking the second again
```

Comment: Please don't just give people code on questions like this. This question should be voted down, voted closed, and voted deleted. We're not here to do people's homework for them.